# How do you make a rectangle(HTML element) controllable with the arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do you make a rectangle or any other HTML element but lets say for example a rectangle be able to move around and have that movement controlled by the arrow keys ( with the e.keycode and case #) and then how would you make spaces the rectangle cannot move into? Any help is appreciated in advance.

an example would be like pacman how pac man cant run into the walls

Comment: Are you trying to make this be something like a game? I would look into Canvas instead of HTML elements

Comment: Generally, each part of this has to be coded very manually - handling each key-press event, shifting position each pixel, and having an understanding of where "walls" are and how to prevent collision with them. You're generally going to want a very basic HTML5 game tutorial.

Comment: Look for event detection... `onkeypress`, `onkeydown`...

Comment: http://html5.litten.com/moving-shapes-on-the-html5-canvas-with-the-keyboard/ this is a good tutorial i found for anyone who wants to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/uk3bsho4/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        //left arrow
        if (e.which == 37) {
            $('#box').css('left','-=1');
        }
        //up arrow
        if (e.which == 38) {
           $('#box').css('top','-=1');
        }
        //right arrow
        if (e.which == 39) {
            $('#box').css('left','+=1');
        }
        //down arrow
        if (e.which == 40) {
            $('#box').css('top','+=1');
        }
    });
});
```

You can look up keycodes [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

That said, the best way to do this would be to use HTML5's Canvas. This was just a quick demonstration with a div.

Comment: This works great but do you know how to do it with jquery or jfiddle?

Comment: @CodeNoob: Make sure you're including jquery in your code. Basically, you just need this: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`